# Who did the Spinning Wheel song in the English dub of the Garo Season 1 OVA?

Tags: music, garo

There's "Spinning Wheel" ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAtM57JXe8M)) song sung near the end of the *Garo* Season 1 OVA. Who sung it?

My guess is Saxton/Rial, but I can't find any answer.